# How to override materialize css in React

Tags: css, reactjs, materialize

I am using react to build simple app, and using Materilize css. In my UserProfile Component class importing UserProfile.css `import "./UserProfile.css`.

```
/* UserProfile.css */ 

.custom-class {
  margin-top: 30 !important;
  color: pink;
}
```

UserProfile in render method have

```
<h1 className="custom-class">Title</h1> // Margin is not applyed, but color is pink
```

I have an option to

```
<h1 style={{ marginTop: 30, color: "pink" }}>Title</h1>
```

this works fine, but I prefer style code in css files.

I am not sure maybe that issue has no relation to overriding.

Comment: Hello, you should use `px` in css files please change your code to`margin-top: 30px !important;` and try again

Comment: @octobus YES, Stupid me, thanks a lot

Comment: Believe me it happens a lot, don't worry :) I also post an answer. Good luck with your project.

Comment: @octobus Thanks. I don't know, do I have to delete question(cause the issue has no relation with overriding)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `px` in css files, change your code to `margin-top: 30px !important;` and it should work.

And if you want to check overriding issues in css, you can inspect your code(with right click your browser and choose inspect) and check if its crossed or not.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use camelCase for your classname, so `.customClass` instead of `.custom-class`.

Then your import statement should look like:

```js
import css from './UserProfile.css`;
```

and in your component:

```js
<h1 className={css.customClass}>Title</h1>
```

Read up on [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a unit for `margin-top` in your css class

```
.custom-class {
  margin-top: 30px !important;
  color: pink;
}
```